# Disable copy on select

Tags: macos, mac

I have found a lot of post about turning on that function, but in my case, I want to disable it. It started recently and it's driving me insane. I just want to have the classic cmd c, cmd v and stop this copy-on-select.

Mac OS 10.14.6

Many thanks

Comment: In every application, or…? Have you ever installed a third party app that enabled this feature in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for my case: PopClip extension.

After updating to macOS 10.14 Mojave for the first time:

Problem: PopClip's copy and paste, spelling replacement etc. are not working immediately after updating to Mojave.

Solution: The following steps should resolve the problem. If not, please get in touch.

1. Quit PopClip
2. Go to System Preferences → Security and Privacy → Privacy → Acccessibility
3. In the list "Allow the apps below to control your computer", highlight PopClip and then remove it using the "-" (minus) button.
4. Use the "+" button add PopClip again to the "Allow the apps below to control your computer" list.

I hope that will help someone.

Comment: Please see https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts Thanks.